# Transforming an index to date in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a simple PANDAS dataframe:

```
              V1
     Index
      1      5
      2      6
      3      7
      4      8
      5      9
      6      10
```

I want to fit an ARMA model from statsmodels. When I try to do it, I get the following:

```
 ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

I guess it means that the index is not set as a date. How can I transform the index to a date? I consider the current index to be days, so in the above example the dataframe runs for 6 days. How can I make PANDAS/statsmodels understand that it is dates of daily frequency? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably set the index to be daily ending today.

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(end=pd.datetime.today(), periods=len(df), freq='1D')
```